When is solution to SDE is a martingale?
Suppose I have the following SDE: $$dX_t=a(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dB_t$$
When is $X_t$ a martingale? I know that the coefficient near $dt$ (drift term) should be zero. But is this enough?
For example, consider the following SDE: $$dX_t= 3X_tdt+\sqrt{X_t}dB_t, X_0=x_0$$
For what values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ is $Y_t=e^{-aX_t^b+c}$ a martingale?
I've applied the Ito's formula to get the SDE for $Y_t$, but what next?

For your first question, no, it’s not enough. a sufficient condition is zero drift + deterministic $\sigma(t, X_t)$

In the provided example $\sigma=\sqrt{X_t}$ is not deterministic. Does it mean that $Y_t$ is never a martingale?

No, I said about whether $X_t$ can be martingale. However, you can do the same think for $Y_t$ by finding its SDE.

That's what I'm talking about. Clearly, the differential equation will contain non-deterministic coefficient near $dB_t$, so it is not martingale. Am I correct?

If you have some well-defined process $X_t=\int_0^t a_sds+\int_0^t \sigma_sdB_s,t\leq T$ a sufficient condition is: $a=0$ and $E[\int_0^T \sigma^2_sds]<\infty$

You said you got already the SDE for $Y_t$, could you show us this SDE. Besides, I note that with $a = 0$, clearly $Y_t$ is a constant, so martingale.

@NN2 , $dY_t=Y_t\left(\left( -3abX_t^b+ab\left(abX_t^{2b-1}+X_t^{b-1}(1-b)\right)\right)dt-abX_t^{b-\frac{1}{2}}dB_t\right)$

@eMathHelp from the SDE, we can say that the sufficient condition is $a = 0$. Don't know whether this condition is necessary or not.

For first question: A martingale satisfies $E[M_t]=E[M_0]$ and so here we have
$$E[X_t]=E[X_0]+\int_0^tE[a(s,X_s)]ds,$$
which means that we need the second term to be identically zero.
For the second question: we take Itô derivative
$$dY_t=-aY_t b X^{b-1}_t dX_t+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{X_t}\right)^2Y_t b aX_{t}^{b-2}\left(b\left(aX_t^{b}-1\right)+1\right)dt$$
$$dY_t=-aY_t b X^{b-1}_t \sqrt{X_t}dB_t+\left(-3aY_t b X^{b}_t+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{X_t}\right)^2Y_t b aX_{t}^{b-2}\left(b\left(aX_t^{b}-1\right)+1\right)\right)dt$$
So we need
$$-3aY_t b X^{b}_t+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{X_t}\right)^2Y_t b aX_{t}^{b-2}\left(b\left(aX_t^{b}-1\right)+1\right)=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow-3aY_t b X^{b}_t+\frac{1}{2}Y_t (ab)^2X_{t}^{2b-1}-\frac{1}{2}Y_t ab^2 X_{t}^{b-1}+\frac{1}{2}Y_t ab X_{t}^{b-1}=0.$$
So here we need $b=1$ to get the last two terms to cancel out.
Sum of the first two terms will be zero when $-3+\frac{1}{2}a=0\Rightarrow a=6$.
Another possible choice is $a=b=0$.

I think, it should be $\frac{1}{2}Y_t(ba)^2X_t^{2b-1}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}Y_t(ba)^2X_t^b$.

@PaulR I agree. Are you sure you copied the right $Y_t$? It seems it might be missing a drift term e.g. $exp(-aX^b_t+ct)$.

It is correct. But everything you'ver written is correct since when $b=1$: $X_t^b=X_t^{2b-1}=X_t$.

@PaulR I didn't get 2b-1. I got 2(b-1) from taking double derivative of $exp(-aX^b+c)$.

In the Itô derivative $\frac{1}{2}Y_t b aX_{t}^{b-2}(b(aX_t^{b}-1)+1)$ should me multiplied by $\left(\sqrt{X_t}\right)^2$.

@PaulR oh yes sorry, thank you.
